# Is there a way to make Json.Net deserialize to a concrete type for a property declared as "object"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's say I have a JSON document that looks like this:

```
{
    "Id" : "233124",
    "RequestDate" : "2019-11-25T10:00:00"
    "RequestPayload" : {
        "Id" : "123abc",
        "Url" : "http://blah.example/api/action",
        "PostData" : "insert random post data here"
    }
}
```

And I have a couple of C# POCOs that look like this:

```
public class RequestLog {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public object RequestPayload { get; set; }
}

public class RequestPayload {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string PostData { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to have Json.Net deserialize the document such that the `RequestLog.RequestPayload` property is of type `RequestPayload`, even though it is declared as `object`? The goal would be to cast it back to `RequestPayload` in order to manipulate it, like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestLog>(json, ...);
var requestPayload = (RequestPayload)request.RequestPayload;
// do other stuff with requestPayload here
```

I can't change the declaration of `RequestLog`, as it is in a NuGet package I don't control. I looked into creating a custom converter, and it seems like it *should* be possible, but I am utterly stumped as to how to pull it off.

Comment: Why type it as `object` instead of `RequestPayload`?

Comment: @Amy honestly, I'm not sure. I think it's because `RequestLog` really wasn't intended to be manipulated this way, it's just supposed to be a DTO for storing log entries.

Comment: If the deserialized classes are simple, maybe create a copy classes you can change. And then auto-map them back onto the original ones.

Comment: @UchenduNwachuku You can use "dynamic" and map them to RequestPayload again if you can't assign it right away.

Comment: @ChinmayKale careful with dynamic. DLR execution is slower than CLR execution and anything that touches anything declared `dynamic` will pass through the DLR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom converter for your `RequestLog` class:

```
public class RequestLogConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(RequestLog);

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Start by running the default serialisation
        var log = new RequestLog();
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), log);

        // Manually deserialize RequestPayload
        log.RequestPayload = jObject["RequestPayload"].ToObject<RequestPayload>();

        return log;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestLog>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new RequestLogConverter() }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was hoping for. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you must declare this `RequestPayload` property of the `RequestLog` as an `object`, and you don't need this code to be reusable, you can brute force this.

```
JContainer json = GetMySerializedContentAsJson(content);
RequestPayload payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestPayload>(json["RequestPayload"]);
RequestLog log = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestLog>(json);
log.RequestPayload = payload;//=>you should now have your object.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `RequestLog` class,

Change:

```
public object RequestPayload { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public RequestPayload RequestPayload { get; set; }
```

And then you'll be able to use it after deserialization, without having to cast it:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestLog>(json, ...);
var requestPayload = result.RequestPayload;
// do other stuff with requestPayload here
```

Comment: I can't; it is in a NuGet package I do not control.

Comment: And why exactly would that matter? If you have it referenced, you should be fine.

Comment: @UchenduNwachuku Do you control the definition of `RequestLog`?

Comment: @K.AlanBates no I do not. :(